# webserver speed for Europe and China

Tags: web-server, vps

Where a looking for a new VPS host for our websites. We have a website for the European market and one for the Chinese market.
Ideal for me would be one host for both the website so i can control everything better.

But I was wondering if my server would be located in Europe, would our Chinese clients have fast enough access to it. Or would i need a different server in China?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That mainly depends on the hosting company and their connectivity configurations versus your expectations/requirements.

Comment: Exactly, The round-trip time from a client in China to your server and back can never be less than the time it takes light to make the same trip. You'll need to figure out of this additional delay is acceptable.

Comment: The real delay will be higher, since networks are not as fast as light, and it depends on the quality of your hosting company's network and peering. You'll need to figure out how high the delay is (measure it or search for info) and if this additional delay is acceptable to your needs.